# RESTful - Getting null in Queryparam

Tags: java, web-services, rest, extjs, extjs4

Getting the response as null.

here is my code

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/")
public class HelloWorldREST {

@POST
@Path("/submitValue")
public Response responseMsg(@QueryParam("name") String name,@QueryParam("email") String email,@QueryParam("date") Date date) {      
String output = date+email+name;
System.out.println(output);     

return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

}

Here is the call to the URL

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
method : 'post',
url: 'rest/submitValue/',
//success: someFn,
//failure: otherFn,
params: 
{ 
name: Ext.getCmp('name').getValue(),
email : Ext.getCmp('email').getValue(),
date : Ext.getCmp('date').getValue()

}
});
```

i am checked that when i send this request parameter got passed ... so no chance that their value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your rest method i.e HelloWorldREST.responseMsg should not be post because it does not have requestBody. It should be get method. Always remember if you want to send data as query param(url param) always use get and if you want send data in request body use POST.

Now second thing since you want send data as query param you can do it two ways. Make sure you are getting values from your queries Ext.getCmp('name').getValue()  , you can check their values in chrome developer console.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'rest/submitValue?name=' + Ext.getCmp('name').getValue() + '&email=' + Ext.getCmp('email').getValue() + '&date=' + Ext.getCmp('date').getValue(), 
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {

            },
            failure:function(response){

            }
        });



Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'rest/submitValue?name=' + Ext.getCmp('name').getValue() + '&email=' + Ext.getCmp('email').getValue() + '&date=' + Ext.getCmp('date').getValue(), 
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                name: Ext.getCmp('name').getValue(),
                email : Ext.getCmp('email').getValue(),
                date : Ext.getCmp('date').getValue()
            }
            success: function (response) {

            },
            failure:function(response){

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data to server using data: instead of params:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
method : 'post',
url: 'rest/submitValue/',
//success: someFn,
//failure: otherFn,
data: 
{ 
name: Ext.getCmp('name').getValue(),
email : Ext.getCmp('email').getValue(),
date : Ext.getCmp('date').getValue()

}
});
```

Three things I see here

1. Which version of jquery are you using?? if its < 1.9.0 then you should use `type:` instead of `method:`

Definition of type: from jquery website:

```
type (default: 'GET')
Type: String
An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0.
```

2. Your Controller(HelloWorldREST) doesn't have `@Component` or `@Controller` annotation on it.
3. From Rest perspective, For a POST call you should not be using query params instead of that send data as payload. And add `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` on your controller.

This might help...